# Django Creating A Team Function

Tags: python, django, database, psql, invite

I want to design a simple app using Django. The design is as follows:

Each user has their own unique ID in the database called `id` which exists in the `auth_user` table already equipped with Django. Then I have a `Team_ID` which is another unique id that represents a team in table called `team_profile`. In this table I have the following columns: `Member1, Member2, Member3`. Currently, a user can create a team and this will set `Member1` to the `id` if the creator.

Each user also has a profile page and in this profile page their is an `invite button`. This is where I am stuck. I am trying to write the invite function but I have absolutely no idea where to start. In the ideal world, I would like a notification to be sent to the `invitee` and the `invitee` can accept or decline the invitation. If the member accepted the invitation then `Member2` will have this person's `id`. I am currently reading up on a lot of stuff but in the meantime if anyone of you guys have any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to engineer your problem, I'm gonna suggest one, but eventually you may adapt it to your need ( i don't know your project in dept )

```
TeamMembership:
   user1: user that send the request
   user2: user that receive the request
   status: here you can create a choice field where 1=pending, 2=accepted, 3=declined
```

The next thing you have to do is to manage the membership filtering based on the status.
This is a minimalistic approach that you can extend with for example the date of the invite etc.